# How to annotate a certain point on a bar chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(month = c("Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", 
                      "May", "Jun", "Jul"), 
              site = c("Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Borth", "Clarach", 
                     "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach", "Clarach"), 
              organic = c(10,20,30,40,50), 
              inorganic = c(90,80,70,60,50), 
              se = c(2,3,1,4,3))
```

and have used it to make this bar chart in ggplot thanks to someone kindly answering my previous question:

```
df %>% 
       tidyr::pivot_longer(c("organic", "inorganic")) %>%
       mutate(se = ifelse(name == "inorganic", NA, se)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = site, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_col() + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) +
   facet_grid(~month) +     
   scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(x, "%"))
```

I'm just wondering if it's possible to annotate the graph to label one bar? It can either be by adding for an asterix onto the chart and then adding this to the legend as "potential reproductive event" or by adding that text directly onto the bar chart? I'd like it to be on the bar that shows Clarach in May if possible. Thanks so much for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, given the orientation and lack of empty space on your plot, that your second option would be best:

```r
df %>% 
       tidyr::pivot_longer(c("organic", "inorganic")) %>%
       mutate(se = ifelse(name == "inorganic", NA, se)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = site, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_col() + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(min = value - se, max = value + se)) +
   geom_text(data = data.frame(site = "Borth", value = 55, name = "organic", 
                               month = "Jul"),
             aes(label = "*"), size = 5) +
   facet_grid(~month) +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste(x, "%")) +
  labs(caption = "*Potential reproductive event")
```

[image]